# Is there a way to enable/disable draggable functionality with Vue.Draggable?

Tags: vue.js

I have a scenario where the wrapped elements should only be draggable upon meeting certain conditions. I handled it in the HTML like this:

```
<draggable v-if='somePassingConditions'>
<my-component></my-component>
</draggable>
<my-component v-else></my-component>
```

I'm trying to not put the if-else condition in the template. Is there a way to enable or disable the drag functionality with Vue.Draggable? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 <draggable :disabled='somePassingConditions'>
   <my-component></my-component>
 </draggable>
```

Here is an example from draggable offical repo: https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next/blob/master/example/components/simple.vue

Also this link may be helpful: https://sortablejs.github.io/vue.draggable.next/#/simple

Comment: I actually just also saw in their docs it supports the Sortable options. Using the 'disabled' prop is what I was looking for! Thanks!